# pyspark not connecting to local cassandra

Tags: python, pyspark, cassandra, datastax, spark-cassandra-connector

I am trying to read from a cassandra table using pyspark.
The code im using is shown below

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pyspark import *
import os
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.12:3.0.0 --conf spark.cassandra.connection.host=127.0.0.1 pyspark-shell'
conf = SparkConf().set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1").set("spark.cassandra.connection.port", "9042").setAppName("Sentinel").setMaster("spark://Suraj-Vashistha-Laptop:7077")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

table_df = sqlContext.read\
        .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")\
        .options(table='movies', keyspace='practice')\
        .load()
```

I have even used the spark-cassandra-connector version 3.0.0 , python 3

Spark is Up and running as shown below:

[image]

So as shown above there is a spark instance that got initialized and its in waiting state.
It is running in default localhost:8080

Cassandra is also up and running:
[image]

Cassandra is also running on localhost:9042

So both are on the local machine itself.
Despite all this I am still unable to connect and run the code.
I get the following error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o36.load.
: java.io.IOException: Failed to open native connection to Cassandra at {127.0.0.1:9042} :: Could not reach any contact point, make sure you've provided valid addresses
```

There are similar questions on stack overflow but they are all 2 or 3+ yrs old and none of the answers worked for me. Hence, I have asked this again for fresh perspective.

My cassandra version details are [cqlsh 6.0.0 | Cassandra 4.0 | CQL spec 3.4.5 | Native protocol v5]

I have kept everything in its latest versions only.

So, I am unable to figure out what went wrong cause everything seems to be running but error says could not reach any contact point. What went wrong??

**EDIT**:
I was recently able to use the exact same code and connect to a cassandra database hosted on a different IP(10.160.0.2) but for localhost it does not work.

**EDIT2**:
I executed the same code(The one where I have localhost and not the first edit IP) line by line on the spark-shell. I launched it as spark-shell --packages *the cassandra connector of datastax*.
So, I observed that all works fine till I reach the .load() or .show() or .first().
I could do the following

```
val conf = new SparkConf(true).set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", cassandraHost)
val sc = new SparkContext("spark://" + sparkMasterHost + ":7077", "example", conf)
val rdd = sc.cassandraTable(keyspace, table)
```

At this point the output(which I have put on the next line ) is an object created and no error is found till now

```
rdd: com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD[com.datastax.spark.connector.CassandraRow] = CassandraTableScanRDD[0] at RDD at CassandraRDD.scala:18
```

The issue happens next when I try to do rdd.show() or rdd.first() or rdd.collect().
And I get the same error I have posted in the question above(failed to open native connection, could not reach any contact point).

Comment: do you have cassandra configured with SSL?

Comment: No, Since it was just localhost I did not configure SSL. Is it a requirement?

Comment: No. It's not a requirement. I suspect that it could be misconfiguration...

Comment: Okay, as i said in the edit. It worked for a different IP but does not work for localhost. Its kind of weird why, cause i did not change anything other than put the new IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This exception indicates that you most likely have a network connectivity issue:

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to open native connection to Cassandra at {127.0.0.1:9042} :: \
  Could not reach any contact point, make sure you've provided valid addresses
```

Your pyspark app cannot connect to `localhost` on port `9042`. Check that you don't have software firewalls such as `iptables` or `firewalld` that is preventing access to the Cassandra node.

One other thing to check is the IP you've configured for `rpc_address`. As an alternative for your test, set the RPC address to your laptop's IP and restart Cassandra. Then set `spark.cassandra.connection.host` to your laptop's IP in your pyspark configuration to see if it works.

As a side note, you stated this in your second edit:

> I launched it as spark-shell --packages the cassandra connector of datastax. So, I observed that all works fine till I reach the .load() or .show() or .first().

The reason for that is evaluations in Spark are lazy -- nothing is executed until you call an action. You don't see any errors until you call an action like `collect()` because nothing gets executed until that point in your code. Cheers!

Comment: `.load` will try to fetch metadata anyway, so it requires properly working connection

Comment: Yes, I agree it does. :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. Yes, the issue was with iptables preventing access. Its working fine now. thanks a lot.